# Create more JCombobox in JTable with different values?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to create a JTable with JCombobox. In that JTable 3 columns having JComboBox with different data. I tried through DefaultCellEditor, but all the JCombobox having the same data.

Can anyone Help me to achieve the same.

Thanks in Advance.

```
public class CustomComboEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    private DefaultComboBoxModel model;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel model1;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel model2;

    public CustomComboEditor() {
        super(new JComboBox());
        this.model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ((JComboBox) getComponent()).getModel();
        this.model1 = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ((JComboBox) getComponent()).getModel();
        this.model2 = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ((JComboBox) getComponent()).getModel();

    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int col) {
        try {
            model.removeAllElements();
            model.addElement("");
            String sql = "select query 1";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                model.addElement(rs.getString(1));
            }



            model1.removeAllElements();
            model1.addElement("");
            String sql1 = "select query 2";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                model1.addElement(rs.getString(1));
            }

            /*model2.removeAllElements();
            model2.addElement("");
            model2.addElement("Male");
            model2.addElement("Female");*/

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Order_Enquiry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, col);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) `} catch (SQLException ex) {
        }` should be `} catch (SQLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();
        }` until you have proper logging in place.  **Never ignore exceptions** until such times as you can explain in code (or code comments) why they can safely be ignored.  In the case of an `SQLException` that time is **..never.**

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, yes i accept, but here its not showing any kind of exceptions (SQL, Normal). The problem is public CustomComboEditor() {
        super(new JComboBox());
        this.model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ((JComboBox) getComponent()).getModel();
        this.model1 = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ((JComboBox) getComponent()).getModel();
        this.model2 = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ((JComboBox) getComponent()).getModel();

    }, I created single JCombobox, Instead of that can use multiple JCombobox, I tried, but not having too much luck.

Comment: *"yes i accept,.."*  Don't 'accept', **edit** *"..but here its not showing any kind of exceptions.."*  With that code, and you're surprised?!?  BTW - 1) Don't put umcompilable code snippets in comments where they are unreadable. 2) Do act on my **first suggestion.**  I have now voted to close for lack of one.

Comment: *"Now i edited... "*  And yet there is ***still no MCVE.***  I've banged my head against this wall enough.  I'm out of here...

Answer (score 2):

```
this.model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ((JComboBox) getComponent()).getModel();
this.model1 = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ((JComboBox) getComponent()).getModel();
this.model2 = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ((JComboBox) getComponent()).getModel();
```

`model`, `model1` and `model2` are 3 references pointing to the *same object*. So when you run `model1.removeAllElements();` you are removing all the elements you just stored previously.

But one single model is probably fine. The problem is currently you are running the exact same queries, regardless of where you are in the table, so you can't hope to have different combobox entries in different cells. Instead you should have something more or less like:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int col) {

    model.removeAllElements();
    model.addElement("");

    if(col==0){
        // Prepare query 1
        sql = ...

    }else if(col==1){
        // Prepare query 2
        sql = ...

    }else
       ...

    // run query
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    // Fill the model
    while (rs.next()) {
        model.addElement(rs.getString(1));
    }

    return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, col);
}
```